# Qatar Airways Free stopover/complimentary hotel

Tags: air-travel, bookings, qatar-airways, doha

Qatar airways offer free stopover and complimentary with their [+Qatar program](https://discoverqatar.qatarairways.com/us-en/plusqatar). Does it require the ticket to be purchased from their official website or can it be purchased from any travel agency and still be eligible for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://discoverqatar.qatarairways.com/us-en/contact-us/):

> 16. Can passengers access this offer if they book through their travel agent or any other booking channel?
>
> Yes, this offer is available to all Qatar Airways passengers holding “157” document and traveling on Qatar Airways flights (no code share flight) transiting through Doha for more than 12 hours